# Is the function $f(x) = \begin{cases} \{x\} , x \geq 0 \\ \{- x\} , x < 0 \end{cases}$ even?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Problem  :

Is the function $$f(x) = \begin{cases}   \{x\} , x \geq  0 \\
\{- x\}  , x < 0 \\ \end{cases}$$ even? ($\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part function.)

As I know the definition of odd and even function

If $f(-x) = f(x)$ function is even

If $f(-x) = -f(x) $ the function is odd.

How to find fractional part function whether it is odd or even. Please guide will be of great help thanks.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the fractional part function? According to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalPart.html there are two different definitions.

Comment: @nathan.j.mcdougall That doesn't matter. We are talking about $|x|$

Comment: @Alizter, true, but if we're trying to prove something then it will be useful

Comment: Your function is $x\mapsto\{|x|\}$, that is of the form $x\mapsto g(|x|)$. From there you should be able to conclude.

Comment: @nathan.j.mcdougall I'm not sure I follow, our statement that we are trying to prove is independent of the definition chosen.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

Your function may be better written as $$f(x)=\{|x|\}$$
Now you can see if it is odd or even.